# SQL Обновление нескольких строк одним запросом

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Здравствуйте, у меня есть таблица в которой есть столбцы (**u**, **name** и.д.).
На скрипт приходят данные(много данных) со значениями (**u**, **name** и.д.). Надо обновить все строки по столбцу **u** одним запросом.
Надо что-то вроде такого:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET colum_name1 = VALUES('value1', 'value2', ..., 'valuenN'),
    colum_name2 = VALUES('value1', 'value2', ..., 'valuenN') 
WHERE colum_name3 IN ('value1', 'value2', ...,'valuenN');
```

Comment: Вы в условиях where в update задайте что бы оно обрабатывало все нужные строчки, он все и обновит

Comment: Я добавил что мне примерно нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Боюсь только как то так:

```
UPDATE table_name
  JOIN (
        select 'val1x' as v1, 'val1y' as v2, 'val1z' as v3
         union
        select 'val2x', 'val2y', 'val2z'
         union
        select 'val3x', 'val3y', 'val3z'
       ) A
    ON A.v3=table_name.colum_name3
SET colum_name1 = A.v1,
    colum_name2 = A.v2
```

Или использовать REPLACE, по синтаксису совпадающий с INSERT, при условии, что colum_name3 первичный или уникальный ключ. Но при этом записи будут удалятся и вставляться, что может плохо отразится на связанных таблицах.

Comment: Спасибо за решение проблемы.
Только у меня вопрос. Почему в строке 

    `select 'val1x' as v1, 'val1y' as v2, 'val1z' v3`
В последнем значении отсутствует **as**

Comment: @Kasper Пропустил :) Вообще эти AS только для наглядности, MySQL как и многие другие СУБД этого не требуют, можно имена колонок и без них писать

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант 1:**

```
UPDATE `table` SET `name`= CASE
WHEN `name`='test' THEN 'testing'
WHEN `name`='test2' THEN 'testing2'
WHEN `name`='test3' THEN 'testing3' ELSE `test`
END ...
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
INSERT INTO `table` (u, name, age) VALUES 
('value1', 'value2', 5), 
('value1', 'value2', 28), 
('value1', 'value2', 28) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), age = VALUES(age)
```

U - уникальный ключ

Я Вам советую, не использовать данные конструкции, а выполнять обновление через одну команду в наборе команд транзкакции, так получается время блокировки на отдельную запись намного меньше и работает это быстрее и по "факту".

Comment: а что за набор транзакций?

Comment: Я не говорил про "набор транзакций", я говорил про набор команд в транзакции. Можно выполнять команды определенными порциями, можно выполнять по одной.

Comment: @Firepro : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/910545/27377