# Эффективный UPDATE MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, запрос

Пример кода:

```
UPDATE tbl_country SET price = CASE
WHEN code = 1 THEN 123;
WHEN code = 2 THEN 456;
…
END
WHERE code IN (1,2,…)
AND id = 222
```

Распространённым советом является не использовать подобные конструкции в силу их неэффективности, а выполнять обновление через одну команду в наборе команд транзкакции, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551450/27377).

Прошу объяснить, будет ли эффективней составить список последовательных UPDATE через запятую, например, так:

```
$query = 
 "UPDATE tbl_country SET price = 123 WHERE code = 1 AND id = 222;
  UPDATE tbl_country SET price = 456 WHERE code = 2 AND id = 222;
  ...
 ";
```

**UPD:**

Ответом на вопросы о произодительности оказался [этот топик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql/44931466), в частности, [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql/44931466#44931466).

Comment: Так name или description?

Comment: насколько велик объем данных у вас, и насколько часты одновременные записи  в таблицу, и как часто вы проводите такой апдейт, чтобы задумываться об эффективности здесь?

Comment: Планируемый объем БД - минимум несколько сотен тысяч строк. За один раз могут обновляться десятки записей (минимум), максимум - несколько сотен в многопользовательском режиме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запросы очень разные. В первом не указано условие `where` и возможно обновляются все записи, во втором выборка осуществляется скорее всего по первичному ключу и обновляются 3 записи. Сложно понять чего вы хотите сделать, но дам вам несколько советов.

В общем случае в `case` нет ничего неэффективного, так как он будет работать с уже выбранными строками и если вам надо смапить одни значения на другие, то используйте его.

Чтобы делать предположения об эффективности изучите работу [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html), и научитесь профилировать своё приложение.

Избегайте преждевременной оптимизации. В случае, когда надо обновить значения в таблице один раз (раз в полгода решили заменить test на testing) эффективность не так уж и важна.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нет, не раз в полгода, в БД изменения могут вноситься ежеминутно разными пользователями. Условие присутствует (второй пример).

Comment: Первый запрос не похож на те, которыми обычно вносят изменения пользователи :-) Если запросов пока нет, то сперва напишите их (они могут оказаться совсем не такими как в примере), а для оценки их эффективности используйте explain.