# Как правильно составить sql запрос с условием?

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Я не могу понять,как можно создать `sql` `update` запрос который будет обновлять не все 2 столбца а только последние записи этих двух столбцов.

Пытался сделать так:

```
UPDATE logs SET e_date = %s, duration = %s WHERE max(e_date, duration)
```

Comment: Что такое "последние записи столбцов" ? Вы имеете ввиду обновить эти 2 столбца в последней записи таблицы ? А что такое "последняя запись", в sql нет понятия порядка строк и нет понятия "последняя", она может быть последней только при указанном явно порядке строк, укажите в вопросе при какой сортировке запись должна быть последней

Comment: Да,прошу прощения что не так выразился.Я имел в виду *обновить эти 2 столбца в последней записи таблицы*

Comment: Так как у вас MySQL наобходимо использовать синтаксис update с join. Как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551441/194569 .  В подзапросе вы должны получить собственно те значения, которые идентифицируют последнюю строку, т.е. что то вроде `select max(e_date) e_date, max(duration) duration from Table` и по этим полям выполнять соединение (в ON). Ну и имя обновляемой таблицы как бы должно присутствовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> обновить эти 2 столбца в последней записи таблицы – Raharasomaha

```sql
UPDATE logs 
SET e_date = %s, 
    duration = %s 
ORDER BY e_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Благодарю за ваш ответ.